# How can I pivot wider and transform my data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr, wrangle

I have a data frame like this:

```
tibble(
  School = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4),
  City = c("A","A", "B", "C", "C", "B"),
  Grade = c("7th", "7th", "7th", "6th", "8th", "8th"),
  Number_Students = c(20, 23, 25, 21, 28, 34),
  Type_school = c("public", "public", "private", "public", "public", "private")
  )
```

| ID | School | City | Grade | Number_Students | Type_school |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 7th | 20 | public |
| 2 | 1 | A | 7th | 23 | public |
| 3 | 2 | B | 7th | 25 | private |
| 4 | 3 | C | 6th | 21 | public |
| 5 | 3 | C | 8th | 28 | public |
| 6 | 4 | B | 8th | 34 | private |

The unit of analysis is the classrooms, but I would like to turn it into a data frame where the unit of analysis is the school, but with some computations. Like this:

```
tibble(
  School = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  City = c("A", "B", "C", "B"),
  N_6th = c(0, 0, 1, 0), # here is the number of grade 6h classrooms in each school 
  N_7th = c(2,1,0,0),
  N_8th = c(0,0,1,1),
  Students_6th = c(0, 0, 25, 0), # here is the number of students in grade 6th from each school (the sum of all 7th grade classrooms from each school)
  Students_7th = c(43, 25, 0, 0), 
  Students_8th = c(0, 0, 28, 34),
  Type_school = c("public", "private", "public", "private")
)
```

| School | City | N_6th | N_7th | N_8th | Students_6th | Students_7th | Students_8th | Type_school |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 43 | 0 | public |
| 2 | B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 0 | private |
| 3 | C | 1 | 0 | 1 | 25 | 0 | 28 | public |
| 4 | B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 34 | private |

I'm trying the pivot_wider(), but that's not enough for my needs. I need to sum the number of classrooms of the same grade in each school and the number of students in the same grade from each school.

Comment: What exactly did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a group by and return the count, and the `sum` of 'Number_Students' and then use `pivot_wider` with `names_from` specified as the 'Grade' and the `values_from` as a vector of columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(School, City, Grade, Type_school) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), Students = sum(Number_Students), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Grade, values_from = c(N, Students), values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  School City  Type_school N_7th N_6th N_8th Students_7th Students_6th Students_8th
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>       <int> <int> <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1 A     public          2     0     0           43            0            0
2      2 B     private         1     0     0           25            0            0
3      3 C     public          0     1     1            0           21           28
4      4 B     private         0     0     1            0            0           34
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach: Not comparable with the perfect approach of akrun, but it contains some interesting feature how we could get the same result:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(School, City, Grade, Type_school),
              names_from = "Grade",
              values_from = "Number_Students",
              values_fn = list(Number_Students = length),
              values_fill = 0,
              names_glue = "N_{Grade}") 

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(School, City, Grade, Number_Students),
              names_from = Grade,
              values_from = Number_Students,
              values_fn = list(Number_Students = sum),
              names_glue = "Students_{Grade}"
              ) %>% 
  right_join(df1, by=c("School", "City"))
```

```
  School City  Students_7th Students_6th Students_8th Type_school N_7th N_6th N_8th
   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>       <int> <int> <int>
1      1 A               43           NA           NA public          2     0     0
2      2 B               25           NA           NA private         1     0     0
3      3 C               NA           21           28 public          0     1     1
4      4 B               NA           NA           34 private         0     0     1
```